# How to copy audio & video streams without re-encoding in GStreamer?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, gstreamer, media

In `ffmpeg` you can use "-c:a copy -c:v copy" to copy audio & video streams without re-encoding the output file, this is the way if you want to make little details in shorter time, like trims.

However in my case I'm using GStreamer, is it possible?

Comment: Please read the Blurb on the `ffmpeg` tag you chose. Your question here is off-topic, it belongs over at [su].

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible

Here an example for mp4 with h264 / aac, In this example your are only demuxing the h264 aac without reencoding.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=1sec-chess-440hz_22.mp4 ! qtdemux name=d d.video_0 ! queue ! h264parse ! mp4mux name=m ! filesink location=test_new.mp4 d.audio_0 ! queue ! aacparse ! m.
```

Best regards